# Help understanding datasheet of battery charger IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging, datasheet

I intend to use the [TI BQ25798](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25798.pdf) battery charger IC for powering a hobby project. The specs look nice and I could power my project either from external power supply or battery or even solar panel.

However, I have some trouble understanding the datasheet.
My project uses a microcontroller with a maximum supply voltage of 3.6 V. I plan on using a LiFePO<sub>4</sub> battery cell, which should work while being limited to 3.6 V.

Now the datasheet of the BQ25798 states in section 7.1 that the SYS voltage can be 0.3 V lower than the BAT voltage. Great. However, in section 8.1 the datasheet states that the system is regulated at a voltage slightly higher that battery voltage. Not great, and seemingly contradictory.

Finally, I cannot understand how to set SYS voltage. V_SYSMAX_REG_RNG ranges from 3.2 V to 19 V, but I can't find any way to control this; not via external components, nor via I2C.

So what's going on here? Can I set the IC to have a maximum output voltage of 3.6 V?

Maybe I am trying to make things too complicated, and I should just settle with using an additional voltage regulator in front of my microcontroller, but I thought it would be nice to forgo this extra wasted energy when having a fancy battery charger IC available.

Comment: It does seem like that it isn't possible to have a lower SYS voltage than the battery voltage.

Comment: I'd be fine with SYS being at battery voltage, as long as it never exceeds it. Battery voltage can be set to 3.6V.